# Reading the contents of a zip entry from a zip that is in the form of bytes

Tags: java

I'm calling onto some code that returns me an HTTP response.  I can get the contents of the response which returns me a byte array.  The bytes represent a zip file that I would like to extract and get the contents of a single file (the zip only contains one file).

Currently I have some messy code (I'll need to clean it up if I keep it) that seems to work:

```
    byte[] bytes = response.out.toByteArray();
    ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(input);
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    zip.getNextEntry();
    int data;
    while ((data = zip.read()) != -1) output.write(data);
    output.close();
    zip.close();
    input.close();
    byte[] kmlBytes = output.toByteArray();
    String contents = new String(kmlBytes, "UTF-8");
```

but was wondering whether there was a cleaner way to do the same thing because the above looks incredibly ugly.

Comment: It's OK and will look even uglier once you add the required try/catch blocks and make sure, that you close the streams properly ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to avoid "reinventing the wheel" and reduce clutter and to focus on your app's business logic rather than low-level code like this, you can use [Apache Commons Compress](http://commons.apache.org/compress/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: I want to reinvent the wheel, how to do?

Comment: Read the source code of Apache Commons Compress. Or even better, read the [spec](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT).